# LNK2005 AND LNK1169 Errors - C++

Tags: c++, linker

The code is self explanatory and it involves me testing namespaces, It involves the user inputting three numbers, that are saved to x y and z, then the numbers are all multiplied together, then all divided by each other

I am getting these three errors

```
LNK2005 "int __cdecl Div::doTheMath(int,int,int)" (?doTheMath@Div@@YAHHHH@Z) already defined in Namespacedemo.obj   
LNK2005 "int __cdecl Mul::doTheMath(int,int,int)" (?doTheMath@Mul@@YAHHHH@Z) already defined in Namespacedemo.obj
LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Divide.h"
#include "Multiply.h"
#include <iostream>    
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Divide.h

```
#pragma once
namespace Div
{
    int doTheMath(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int w = x / y / z;
        return w;
    }
}
```

Multiply.h

```
#pragma once
#pragma once
namespace Mul
{
    int doTheMath(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int w = x * y * z;
        return w;
    }
}
```

Namespacedemo.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
    int x;
    int y; 
    int z;
    //Namespaces are 'Mul' & 'Div'
    std::cout << "Please enter 3 numbers" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cin >> z;
    std::cout << Mul::doTheMath(x, y, z);
    std::cout << Div::doTheMath(x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Header files should have declarations, but should not have definitions.

Comment: Including a header file means that everything in the header file gets logically inserted into your .cpp file, as if it appears in there, verbatim. Therefore, you have two .cpp files that define the same exact function, hence the link failure.

Comment: Please paste the full compilation log. It contains information needed to answer your question (for example which file is been compiled, when this error appears) .

Answer (score 0):

This is how your files should look like:

Divide.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Div
{
    int doTheMath(int x, int y, int z);
}
```

Multiply.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Mul
{
    int doTheMath(int x, int y, int z);
}
```

Divide.cpp

```
#include "Divide.h"

namespace Div
{
    int doTheMath(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int w = x / y / z;
        return w;
    }
}
```

Multiply.cpp

```
#include "Multiply.h"

namespace Mul
{
    int doTheMath(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int w = x * y * z;
        return w;
    }
}
```

---

Detailed explanation later...